# spring-data-jpa to mysql connection issue

Tags: mysql, jdbc, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have here mysql connection issue from spring boot application. Will try to provide all the information needed - if something is still missing please ask. I will try to update.

First - as it is a key element here my mysql user has a limit - set to 5. And it can not be increased. Unless I'll find some real argument for that.

I am using mysql driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar
In a spring boot application 1.4.1.RELEASE.

The issue is as follows:
every 6'th attemt to aquire connection ends up with such error message:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.findByMsisdn(Unknown Source)
```

Then - next 5 connections are ok. And it is in a loop  again.

Looks like my spring application is not releasing (somehow) connection after it is used. Or leaves it open till this error occurs.

Functionality that failes - is simple ORM - table mapped to java object using spring.data.repository.

Connection pool configuration:

> db:
>     datasource:
>       url: jdbc:mysql://server1,server2/db
>       username: XXX
>       password: YYY
>       driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>       max-wait: 5000
>       max-active: 2
>       min-idle: 1
>       max-idle: 2

And - there is some outside factor, which is unknown to me. I say this because it is not always failing like that. But just for uncertain period of time.

If somebody has some ideas - please help.